# Tres Llaves foraneas, a primary key

Tags: sql

Hola soy un estudiante apenas voy iniciando y me propuse un problema que es el siguiente. Se sabe que un alumno en un semestre determinado lleva varias asignaturas, y también se sabe que cada materia tiene su nombre y sus unidades. por ejemplo calculo diferencial tiene 5 unidades y cada unidad tiene un objetivo. Por lo que un alumno tiene un promedio para cada unidad y un promedio final por la asignatura. Hice una relación un alumno puede cursar varias materias, una materia lo pueden tomar muchos alumnos (mucho a muchos), una asignatura tiene varias unidades una unidad pertenece a una sola asignatura (1:n), en la tabla detalle_Alumno_materia como hacer que las columnas id_asignatura, id_unidades, id_alumno sean primarias, son únicos para identificar a cada alumno con su promedio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código en MySql es el siguiente.

```
-- una materia tiene varias unidades
  create table asignatura (
    id_asignatura int primary key auto_increment,
    nombre varchar(60),
    unidades varchar (20),
    semestre varchar (20),
    creditos int
  );
  alter table asignatura modify unidades integer;

  --tabla unidades representa la unidad de cada materia
  create table unidades (
    id_unidades int primary key auto_increment,
    nombre_unidad varchar (40),
    objetivo text,
    id_materia int,
    foreign key (id_materia) references asignatura (id_asignatura) on delete cascade
  );

  create table detalle_asignatura_alumno(
    id_asignatura int,
    id_unidades int,
    id_alumno int,
    Calificacion float,
    foreign key (id_materia) references materia (id_asignatura),
    foreign key (id_alumno) references alumno (id_alumno),
    foreign key (id_unidades) references unidades (id_unidades)
  );
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! las tablas parecen bien. que intentaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada te impide crear una clave principal con los tres campos cuyos valores quieres impedir que se repitan:

```
ALTER TABLE detalle_asignatura_alumno
  ADD PRIMARY KEY(id_asignatura,id_unidades,id_alumno);
```

Observo que en tu dataset falta crear la tabla `alumno`:

```
create table alumno(
    id_alumno int primary key auto_increment,
    alumno varchar(31)
);
```

Así como una pequeña discrepancia con materia/asignatura:

```
  create table detalle_asignatura_alumno(
    id_asignatura int,
    id_unidades int,
    id_alumno int,
    Calificacion float,
    foreign key (id_asignatura) references asignatura (id_asignatura),
    foreign key (id_alumno) references alumno (id_alumno),
    foreign key (id_unidades) references unidades (id_unidades)
  );
```

Comment: #1005 - No puedo crear tabla `estudiante`.`detalle_asignatura_alumno` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalles…) Me manda este error cuando hago PRIMARY KEY(id_asignatura, id_unidades, id_alumno) despues de calificacion

Comment: Ya pude corregir el error, fue porque no escribí bien el nombre de la tabla, muchas gracias,.

Answer (score -1):

la relación:
alumno 1:n asignatura 1:n unidades.
si cada unidad tiene una calificación y quieres asegurarte que sea un único ingreso, debes cambiar las foreing key de la tabla: detalle_asignatura_alumno , por primary key (la llave la hará el id_alumno, id_asignatura, id_unidad)

nota: la notación para definir tablas, variables, etc por nomenclatura siempre es en inglés, debes acostumbrarte a eso.

Comment: porque en ingles? porqueeeee.. quien dijo que es en ingles???

Comment: La mejor convención es no mezclar idiomas, es decir, no tener unas tablas, campos (o cualquier otra entidad) en inglés y otras en español. Lo demás (utilizar español o inglés) depende únicamente de lo que el quipo de trabajo decida.

Comment: chicos, cuando trabajen en equipos multidisciplinarios y tengan que interactuar con colegas de la india, italianos, rumanos, el estándar es el ingles. 
además existen estándares de buenas prácticas que harán de tu trabajo un trabajo de mejor calidad.